Shadcn not working after installing Vite + React + JS

I create Vite project with React + Javascript (without Typescript)

npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

npx tailwindcss init -p

Then I create jsconfig.json file, copy paste following code
 {
   "compilerOptions": {
     "baseUrl": ".",
     "paths": {
       "@/*": ["./src/*"]
     }
   }
 }


in vite.config.js file
import path from "path"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
})


in Tailwind.config.js


/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}


in Index.css file, I comment all the line of code which is existing earlier, then I add following code

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


install shadcn

npx shadcn@latest init


After successfully installed shadcn, then I add Button components
npx shadcn@latest add button

in app.jsx file



import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{padding:'10px'}}>
      <Button>Button</Button>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

My output like below
the left side button Which I created, the right side button is sample from shadcn website.. may i know where i did the mistake?.

Have you tried importing index.css into your app.js file?

may be there is some line of style conflict on your CSS file. I don't know exact mistake, but what i know if tailwindcss not installed properly, the default styling HTML still exists (like H1 or button tag). same as Shadcn, if some reason not installed properly, they would not getting black button like your image

On step 8, during installation, it will automatically create a components.json file. Make sure the index.css path matches the main style directory path in your project. Also don't forget the flag ("tsx": false) to make sure Shadcn will generate component in Javascript version. Then you can move on to step 9.
{
    "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
    "style": "default",
    "rsc": false,
    "tsx": false,
    "tailwind": {
        "config": "tailwind.config.js",
        "css": "src/index.css",
        "baseColor": "slate",
        "cssVariables": true,
        "prefix": ""
    },
    "aliases": {
        "components": "@/components",
        "utils": "@/lib/utils",
        "ui": "@/components/ui",
        "lib": "@/lib",
        "hooks": "@/hooks"
    },
    "iconLibrary": "lucide"
}

